# Can JQuery.Validate plugin prevent submission of an Ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am using the JQuery form plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to handle the ajax submission of a form. I also have JQuery.Validate (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugged in for my client side validation.

What I am seeing is that the validation fails when I expect it to however it does not stop the form from submitting. When I was using a traditional form (i.e. non-ajax) the validation failing prevented the form for submitting at all.... which is my desired behaviour.

I know that the validation is hooked up correctly as the validation messages still appear after the ajax submit has happened.

So what I am I missing that is preventing my desired behaviour? Sample code below....

```
<form id="searchForm" method="post" action="/User/GetDetails">
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="user.name" />  
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />   
</form>
<div id="detailsView">
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        target: '#detailsView'
    };
    $('#searchForm').ajaxForm(options);

    $('#searchForm').validate({
    rules: {
    username: {required:true}},
    messages: {
    username: {required:"Username is a required field."}}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Berko - Any chance you could pick the correct answer or let us know if it didn't solve your issue?

Comment: I have added an answer below. May or may not help you out.

Answer (score 15):

You need to add a callback function for use with the beforeSubmit event when initializing the ajaxForm():

```
var options = {
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            return $('#searchForm').validate().form();
        },
        target: '#detailsView'
    };
```

Now it knows to check the result of the validation before it will submit the page.

Comment: Oops, I didn't know this question was 7 months old... Oh well!

Comment: +1, Excellent answer. It really helped me out. I'm not using the forms plugin, but, just so other people know, you can do the same thing if you are binding your forms with ajax manually using the $.ajax({...}) method. The only difference is that instead of 'beforeSubmit' it's 'beforeSend'. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

... well it's been a while so my situation has changed a little. Currently I have a submitHandler option passed to the Validate() plugin. In that handler I manually use ajaxSubmit. More a workaround than an answer I guess. Hope that helps.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html

```
var v = jQuery("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({target: "#result"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#contactform').ajaxForm({
  success : FormSendResponse, 
  beforeSubmit:  function(){
    return $("#contactform").valid();
  }
});


$("#contactform").validate();
```

Above code worked fine for me.

Comment: Again, I know this is an old question, but I think is this the best answer. A straightforward, and clean answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a first pass, I'm wondering why the line

```
$("form").validate({
```

doesn't refer to $("searchform"). I haven't looked this up, or tried it, but that just seems to be a mismatch.  Wouldn't you want to call validate on the appropriate form?

Anyway, if this is completely wrong, then the error isn't immediately obvious. :)

Comment: That was an oversight when I posted. But even then it makes no difference as that is the only form on the page - so $('#searchform') is basically equivalent to $('form').

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure all of your input fields have a "name" attribute as well as an "id" attribute. I noticed the jquery validation plugin doesn't function correctly without these.

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is an old question but i will put our solution here for posterity. i personally classify this one as a hack-trocity, but at least it's not a hack-tacu-manjaro

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        target: '#detailsView'
    };

// -- "solution" --
$('#searchForm').submit(function(event) {
  this.preventDefault(event); // our env actually monkey patches preventDefault
                              // impl your own prevent default here
                              // basically the idea is to bind a prevent default
                              // stopper on the form's submit event
});
// -- end --

    $('#searchForm').ajaxForm(options);

    $('#searchForm').validate({
      rules: {
      username: {required:true}},
      messages: {
      username: {required:"Username is a required field."}}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wohoo vote this guy, this.preventDefault(event); works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

May be a 
return false;
on the form will help?
:)
I mean:

```
<form id="searchForm" method="post" action="/User/GetDetails" onSubmit="return false;">
```