# How to use jQuery Validation Plugin with textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, validation

I am having a little bit of trouble understanding how to implement [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). With my form that is being submitted with Ajax:

```
$(document).delegate("'#submit-quote'", "submit", function(){
        var quoteVal = $(this).find('[name="quote"]').val();
        $.post("add.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            var like = $('.quote-wrap span iframe');
            $('.inner').prepend('<div id="'  + data + ' " class="quote-wrap group">' + like + '<div class="quote"><p>' + quoteVal+ '</p></div></div>');
            // console.log("success");
            var id = parseInt(data);
            console.log(id)

// some code after being successfully sent

});
```

After adding validation plugin, how would I set the defaults and make sure it's what I want the form to do?

It's just a textarea, that a user submits a simple quote. (text and numbers) and shouldn't submit anything else. Right now I can submit HTML, or anything else I like.

What do I need to do to make sure the user can't?

I have tried:

Comment: take a look into this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137872/can-jquery-validate-plugin-prevent-submission-of-an-ajax-form


hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is make sure users can't post HTML, then check out this article on StackOverflow: [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding).

Otherwise, you can use jQuery Validation to perform a similar method during validation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#myform").validate();
$("a.check").click(function () {
    if ($("#myform").valid()) {
        //if valid do form submit
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

you can check the validity of the form . if valid do your work . else return false,

check this

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

and one more thing, you are using `submit` event of the form. that causes page refresh. so you have to

return false OR use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/